# Python time app, with tkinter not working

Tags: python, button, tkinter, time

I tried making a basic time application, but, it doesn't work. If you run it, it displays the gui, the no button works (by closing the window). But, the yes button doesn't create a popup telling you the time.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from datetime import datetime

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Helvetica", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Helvetica", 8)


class CurrentTime:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Current Time")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Do you want to know the current time? Y/N", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=11)

        self.time_button = Button(master, text="Yes", command=self.thetime, font=NORM_FONT)
        self.time_button.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=11)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="No", command=master.quit, font=NORM_FONT)
        self.close_button.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=11)

    def thetime(self, master):
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        master.tile("Current Time")
        self.label = Label(master, text="Current Time =", command=current_time, font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Okay", command=master.quit, font=NORM_FONT)
        self.close_button.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=11)


root = Tk()
yes = CurrentTime(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you run it in console, you will get an exception of `missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'`.  Remove the argument `master` from `def thetime(self, master)` and use `self.master` instead of `master` inside the function.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: It is because there are other issues in your code.  Look into the error messages in the console and solve it one by one.

Comment: The code with the problem may only be the "thetime" function, as the rest of the code, I copied, and edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra argument `master` in `def thetime(self, master)`.  Remove the extra argument.  Also you do not need to recreate the `self.label` and `self.close_button` in the function, just update their `text` is enough:

```
def thetime(self):
    self.time_button.destroy()  # remove the 'Yes' button
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.label.config(text="Current Time = "+current_time) # show the current time
    self.close_button.config(text="Okay") # change close_button text to 'Okay'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that you made it clear for me to understand my mistake.